# Can this be solved with a single SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, dml

Is it possible to make a single SQL query to solve this?  There are 4 tables:

- book (id, title, something)
- page (id, book_id, something)
- syntax_error (id, page_id, fixed, something) (fixed - bool)
- lexical_error (id, page_id, fixed, something)

The `book` table has a one-to-many relationship with the `page` table.

A single `page` may contain a `syntax_error` or a `lexical_error` (for this example, impossible to have both errors for one page, and only one error per page) so `page` has a one-to-one relationship with `syntax_error` or `lexical_error`.

How can I find all books without errors?  (How can I get all `book.id` values for page which don`t have any errors or any non-fixed error?)

By using one SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT id, title, ...
FROM book AS b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM page AS p
                  JOIN syntax_error AS se ON p.id = se.page_id
                  WHERE p.book_id = b.id)
      AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM page AS p
                  JOIN lexical_error AS le ON p.id = le.page_id
                  WHERE p.book_id = b.id)
```

Comment: I would probably use this if it wasn't mysql, just because I've read mysql has a hard time with `not exists()` compared to the other alternatives. Still a good answer though, +1. [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: @SqlZim . . . I think `union all` precludes the use of indexes, so this might be much faster than that version.

Answer (score 1):

using `not in()` (removed the previous unioned `not in()`, as it might not take advantage of indexes)

```
select b.id
from book b
where b.id not in (
    select p.book_id 
    from page p
      inner join syntax_error se
        on p.id = se.page_id
       and se.fixed = 0
     )
  and b.id not in (
    select p.book_id 
    from page p
      inner join lexical_error le
        on p.id = le.page_id
       and le.fixed = 0  
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.id
from book b
left outer join page p on p.book_id = b.id
left outer join syntax_error s on s.page_id = p.id
left outer join lexical_error l on l.page_id = p.id
group by b.id
having sum(case s.fixed when 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
and sum(case l.fixed when 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```